# How can I reduce the size of this Ranking Query in MySql?

Tags: mysql, ranking

I've got a ranking query that ranks the performance of teams in challenges.

The hierarchy of data is as follows:
teams have members
members have activities
activities have activitytypes
challenges have activitytypes

If I want to rank the performance all teams in a single challenge, this query works great:

```
SELECT     t.teamID, t.teamName, 
        scoring.challengeID, 
        outerchallenge.name AS ChallengeName, outerchallenge.description AS ChallengeDescription, outerchallenge.startDate, outerchallenge.endDate, 
        scoring.standardValueSum, scoring.standardUnit, scoring.rank 
FROM challenge outerchallenge 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT teamID, challengeID, standardValueSum, standardUnit, FIND_IN_SET(standardValueSum, scores ) AS rank 
        FROM ( 
            SELECT teammember.teamID, mc.challengeID, sum(v.standardValue) standardValueSum, v.standardUnit 
            FROM v_activitystats v 
                INNER JOIN memberchallenge mc ON v.memberID = mc.memberID AND v.standardValue > 0 
                INNER JOIN teammember ON v.memberID = teammember.memberID 
                INNER JOIN challenge c ON mc.challengeID = c.challengeID 
                INNER JOIN challengeactivitytype cat ON c.challengeID = cat.challengeID AND cat.activityTypeID = v.activityTypeID 
            WHERE v.activityDate BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.endDate 
                AND c.challengeID = 33  
            GROUP BY standardUnit, challengeID, teamID 
            ) vstats 
    CROSS JOIN ( 
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT standardValueSum ORDER BY standardValueSum DESC ) AS scores 
        FROM ( 
            SELECT teammember.teamID, mc.challengeID, sum(v.standardValue) standardValueSum 
            FROM v_activitystats v 
                INNER JOIN memberchallenge mc ON v.memberID = mc.memberID AND v.standardValue > 0 
                INNER JOIN teammember ON v.memberID = teammember.memberID 
                INNER JOIN challenge c ON mc.challengeID = c.challengeID 
                INNER JOIN challengeactivitytype cat ON c.challengeID = cat.challengeID AND cat.activityTypeID = v.activityTypeID 
            WHERE v.activityDate BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.endDate 
                AND c.challengeID = 33  
            GROUP BY challengeID, teamID 
            ) vstats 
        ) scores 
    ) scoring 

    ON outerchallenge.challengeID = scoring.challengeID 
        INNER JOIN team t ON scoring.teamID = t.teamID
```

### Here is a formatted query: http://mysql.pastebin.com/XggRL5kX

ChallengeID, Team, Ranking
99 Red Team 1
99 Blue Team 2

Once again, this works just fine for a specific challenge, (ID = 33)

I want to get a query with the same sort of rankings, but for multiple challenges, like those that have already ended.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT rankings.teamID, stuff.teamName, rankings.challengeID, 
        rankings.ChallengeName, rankings.ChallengeDescription, rankings.startDate, rankings.endDate, 
        rankings.standardValueSum, rankings.standardUnit, rankings.rank 
FROM challenge chal 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT t.teamID, t.teamName, scoring.challengeID, 
        outerchallenge.name AS ChallengeName, outerchallenge.description AS ChallengeDescription, outerchallenge.startDate, outerchallenge.endDate, 
        scoring.standardValueSum, scoring.standardUnit, scoring.rank 
    FROM challenge outerchallenge 
        LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT teamID, challengeID, standardValueSum, standardUnit, FIND_IN_SET(standardValueSum, scores ) AS rank 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT teammember.teamID, mc.challengeID, sum(v.standardValue) standardValueSum, v.standardUnit 
                FROM v_activitystats v 
                    INNER JOIN memberchallenge mc ON v.memberID = mc.memberID AND v.standardValue > 0 
                    INNER JOIN teammember ON v.memberID = teammember.memberID 
                    INNER JOIN challenge c ON mc.challengeID = c.challengeID 
                    INNER JOIN challengeactivitytype cat ON c.challengeID = cat.challengeID AND cat.activityTypeID = v.activityTypeID 
                WHERE v.activityDate BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.endDate 
                GROUP BY standardUnit, challengeID, teamID ) vstats 
            CROSS JOIN ( 
                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT standardValueSum ORDER BY standardValueSum DESC ) AS scores 
                FROM ( 
                    SELECT teammember.teamID, mc.challengeID, sum(v.standardValue) standardValueSum 
                    FROM v_activitystats v 
                        INNER JOIN memberchallenge mc ON v.memberID = mc.memberID AND v.standardValue > 0 
                        INNER JOIN teammember ON v.memberID = teammember.memberID 
                        INNER JOIN challenge c ON mc.challengeID = c.challengeID 
                        INNER JOIN challengeactivitytype cat ON c.challengeID = cat.challengeID AND cat.activityTypeID = v.activityTypeID 
                    WHERE v.activityDate BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.endDate 
                    GROUP BY challengeID, teamID 
                ) vstats 
            ) scores 
        ) scoring ON outerchallenge.challengeID = scoring.challengeID 
        INNER JOIN team t ON scoring.teamID = t.teamID 
) rankings ON chal.challengeID = rankings.challengeID
WHERE chal.endDate <= current_date()
```

### Here is a formatted query: http://mysql.pastebin.com/mSZwtDm3

But rather than every challenge having a 1st place, and a 2nd place, the rankings are across all of the challenges. Like this

ChallengeID, Team, Ranking
99 Red Team 1
99 Blue Team 2
134 Red Team 3
134 Blue Team 4
443 Red Team 5
442 Blue Team 6

So, I suppose, I'm evaluating the ranking at the wrong place, but I'm sort of out of ideas for how to make this work. How can I get results like this:
ChallengeID, Team, Ranking
99 Red Team 1
99 Blue Team 2
134 Red Team 1
134 Blue Team 2
443 Red Team 1
443 Blue Team 2

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the Oracle clause "PARTITION BY", which would subgroup and then allow you to rank multiple times like you are attempting to do.

Probably the easiest way around that is instead of trying to display the rank, as generated by mySQL, you could create your own.

Here's a better example of doing that than I could formulate, hey it's almost 4am!
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/